# What is the one point compactification of the reals?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, infinity

In several of my questions this theorem has come up. What is the one-point compactification of the reals? Does it have to do with limits and dividing by $0$? I vaguely remember something about a circular number line. Does it apply to complex numbers too? And do numbers such as aleph-null or ordinal infinities mess up this theorem?

Comment: You are overthinking the problem.  Add one point, whose neighborhoods are that point together with complements of compact sets in the real line.  You will indeed get "a circular number line".

Comment: It might be easier to think about if you replace the reals with the open interval $(0,1)$, which is homeomorphic to the reals, and so has a homeomorphic one-point compactification.

Comment: This might be one of the most confused questions I've seen in a while.

Comment: Keyword: "real projective line"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:** Can we write one to one, onto and continious from the circle $S_1$ to $\mathbb R$ ?

The answer is no and it can be shown that if we extract one point from $S_1$, it is possible.

Now the idea is that instead of extractinting one point from $S_1$, let's add one point to $\mathbb R$ so that we can write the map from $S_1$ to $\mathbb R \cup {a} $. As $S_1$ is compact then $\mathbb R\cup {a}$ is compact.

One point compactification is the generelezation of this idea. In general, if you add one point to $\mathbb R^n$ in a appropriate way you will get $S_n$.

Comment: So is it that the reals don't fit a circular number line, but if you add infinity they will?

Comment: @tox123: yes exactly, but think $\infty$ as a symbol.

Comment: does $\infty$ encompasses all infinities?

Comment: $\infty$ is just the symbol used to mean 'a new point'. You could call it $\bullet$ if that makes it less ambiguous for you.

Comment: @tox123: Cardinal and ordinal numbers have nothing to do with this topic. Regarding the extended real numbers $\pm \infty$, you could envision taking the two endpoints of the line and looping them around so that they are the same point: in that sense, $\infty$ encompasses both $\pm \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The one point compactification of the reals is the circumference. Indeed, stereographic projection from the north pole gives a homeo from the circumference without that pole onto the real line, and the inverse is the embedding of the reals into a compact space consisting of just one single additional point. In full generality, for non-compact locally compact Haussdorf space $X$, the one point (or Alexandroff) compactification is just a compact Haussdorf space $X^*$ obtained adding a point to the given one, and all such $X^*$'s are homeomorphic. For complex numbers, which topologically are the real plane, the one point compactification is the sphere, and stereographic projection works the same.